# How inaccurate and in which direction will a vertically mounted flow meter be?

Tags: plumbing, water, irrigation

I use several [Netafim flow meters](https://www.agriculture-xprt.com/products/netafim-model-m-and-wmr-irrigation-water-meters-375592) and I use them successfully without complaint.  However, it has come to my attention that they cannot be used in a vertical orientation. I have two questions about this:

1. How inaccurate would the reading be on a water meter like this if it were put in service vertically?  Are we talking 2% off or 200% off?
2. In which direction (over measures or under measures) would it be off?

Thank you.

Comment: It appears vertical mounting is fine so long as the dial face is horizontal and flow is upwards.  Have you read that document or are you sure you linked the right one?

Comment: Isn't this a case of RTFM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've listed two different meters in your link: the M and the WMR. The M meter must be installed with the dial horizontal. The WMR meter can be installed in any direction with the flow upward in non horizontal positions. You need to determine which ones you actually have. I seriously doubt anyone here can answer your "inaccuracy" questions as it would take a calibrated study against two M meters: one installed correctly and one installed vertically. You might be able to get some more information from the manufacturer on this.